# On page resize, apply function to several items individually

Tags: jquery, html, function, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a jQuery plugin for responsive websites that checks if a table is too big to fit on the page. If so, it should hide the table and show a button. When you click the button, it will open the table in a new window. This prevents tables from breaking responsive layouts.

**The problem:**

I have two functions defined that are started on page load, and page resize:

```
// Call on page load and page resize
tableChecker();
$(window).resize(function () {
    tableChecker();
    resizeUp();
});
```

Currently, the functions are applying to every table on the page equally. However, I need them to apply to each table *specifically*. This means that when it checks the width of the table, it needs to do that for each individual table because they may be different widths.

An example of one of my functions:

```
function tableChecker() {
    var windowWidth = parseInt($(window).width()),
        tableWidth = parseInt($('.responsive-table table').outerWidth());
    if (windowWidth < tableWidth) {
        var finaltableWidth = parseInt($('.responsive-table table').outerWidth());
        $('.responsive-table').prop('title', finaltableWidth);
        $('.viewtable').show();
        $('.responsive-table table').hide();

    }
}
```

**How can I make this function apply to each table individually?**

resize my jsfiddle example -> http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/fg3Eq/5/

*Bonus points if anyone can tell me why the title isn't working on the generated page*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.responsive-table table').outerWidth()` is going to only get the width of the first item in the jQuery selection, you need to loop, with `.each` probably

Comment: Yeah, this got me on the right track. Wrapping each function with $(".rwd-table").each(function(){ // }); and then modifying the selectors inside to "this" worked.

Answer (score 0):

may be this:

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fg3Eq/6/

```
function tableChecker(tableToResize) {
    var windowWidth = parseInt($(window).width()),
        tableWidth = parseInt($(tableToResize).outerWidth());
    if (windowWidth < tableWidth) {
        var finaltableWidth = parseInt($(tableToResize).outerWidth());
        $(tableToResize).attr('data-width', finaltableWidth);
        $('.viewtable').show();
        $(tableToResize).hide();

    }
}

// Show table again if sized back up
function resizeUp(tableToResize) {
    var windowWidth = parseInt($(window).width());
    var minWidth = parseInt($(tableToResize).data('width'));
    if (windowWidth > minWidth) {
        $(tableToResize).show();
        $('.viewtable').hide();
    }
}


$(window).resize(function () {
    tableChecker($('.tbl1'));
    resizeUp($('.tbl1'));
    tableChecker($('.tbl2'));
    resizeUp($('.tbl2'));
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for a more automatic/dynamic way of doing it than adding classes to the tables.